# Spring AOP advice is called several times

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have a method that need to be intercepted before and after execution, so in order to do that I used `AspectJ`

It works great, but for some reason the advice is called several times.

Looking at the call hierarchy I noticed that when calling `joinPoint.proceed();` instead of continuing the method execution, I get to the advice method again.

I can't figure it out why the advice method is being called several times although I'm calling `getCacheableSite(String siteId)` only once.

Spring xml configuration:

```
<bean id="runtimeCacheAspect" class="site.aspect.RuntimeCacheAspect">
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="aspectLogging" ref="runtimeCacheAspect" >
        <!-- @Around -->
        <aop:pointcut id="pointCutAround"
                      expression="execution(public * getCacheableSite(..))" />
        <aop:around method="getData" pointcut-ref="pointCutAround" />

    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Advice:

```
public Object getData(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Object returnObject = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Before");
        returnObject = joinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throw throwable;
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("After");
    }
    return returnObject;
```

The method that needs to be intercepted:

```
    public JsonObject getCacheableSite(String siteId) {
        System.out.println("Method being executed..."); 
}
```

Output:

```
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Before
Method being executed...
After
After
After
After
After
After
After
After
After
After
```

Comment: What version of spring are you using?  It might be an issue with having multiple proxy wrappers?

Comment: @randal4 I'm using spring 4.3.8.RELEASE, I have another advice (which uses proxy) which is implemented on different project.

Comment: Can you please log `"Before " + joinPoint` and `"After " + joinPoint`, respectively? It would be interesting to see if maybe multiple implementations of `getCacheableSite(..)` are intercepted. Please also check if `getData(..)` is called from somewhere else, e.g. from another aspect or from other places in your code.

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks for your comments, `getData(..)` isn't called from anywhere else in the code. regarding loging with the joinpoint the following is added to the Before/After string `execution(JsonObject site.RuntimeCacheable.getCacheableSite(String))`

Comment: I am not a Spring user, but I do know that for pointcut matching Spring uses an AspectJ library. If there was an error that dramatic, I think it would have been found before, so I guess the problem is somewhere in your configuration rather than in the aspect (pointcut + advice) itself. In order to reproduce the problem and help you, it would be nice to see an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, ready to build and run with a Maven project or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue:

```
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" expose-proxy="true">
        <aop:include name="getCacheableSite" />
    </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```